# Unable create process when run pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have searched for the answer with the same problem, but still can't

i used python 3.6.6 , pip version is 19.0.1 
When I run the command like pip -v, pip list through cmd and result error :

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python36\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe" -v'
```

Please help 
this img : https://imgur.com/I7EMq91

Comment: second parameter should be the script to run, not pip

Comment: how command i check version of pip? i want to check version of pip

Comment: pip -v to check version of pip right?, i tried any command of pip like pip list and result that error

Comment: Can you post the command you were trying to use?